# Unable to get authentication code from microsoft azure ad graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have a paid developer account with Microsoft Azure. I have created an app for getting Office365 emails and another app for getting office365 contacts. When I connect to the email app from my application using oauth and I can successfully get the authentication code. However when I try to do the same thing with my contact app no authentication code is returned nor does it show any error. Can anyone suggest what might be the reason behind this ?

Comment: What's the error message? To get the authorization code, the `response_type` must contain `code`. And what's the value of `response_type` when you send the request? You can refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) about the parameters using OAuth 2.0 authorization flow.

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT there is no error message it just keeps static in the login screen instead of redirecting to the specified return url

Comment: Is it helpful to click the sign-in button again?

Comment: @FeiXue-MSFT clicking the sign in button just refreshes the page

Comment: What's the response after you click the sign-in button? You can use the Developer tools of Chrome(F12->Network->check preserve log) to capture the detail response.

Comment: And what's the detailed request URL?